# Handling WM_DROPFILES message doesn't work in Lazarus

Tags: drag-and-drop, lazarus, freepascal

I want to create windows GUI application using Lazarus that able to drag file from explorer to the TEdit widget and show the file path.

I had read and tried some delphi tutorials, it said that you need to handle the WM_DROPFILES message, but I still can't get it works. So I'm thinking if I should try the simple way first by making application that able to drag file to TForm instead.

So I followed [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25427533/844005), but it doesn't work too.

Here is the full code:

```
unit Unit1;

{$mode objfpc}{$H+}

interface

uses
  Windows, Classes, SysUtils, FileUtil, Forms, Controls, Graphics, Dialogs,
  ShellAPI;

type

  { TForm1 }

  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { private declarations }
  public
    { public declarations }
  protected
      procedure WMDropFiles(var Msg: TMessage); message WM_DROPFILES;
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.lfm}

{ TForm1 }

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  DragAcceptFiles(self.Handle, True);
end;

procedure TForm1.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
  DragAcceptFiles(self.Handle, False);
end;

procedure TForm1.WMDropFiles(var Msg: TMessage);
begin
  ShowMessage('hello');  // never gets called
end;

end.
```

The `TForm1.FormCreate` and `TForm1.FormDestroy` are working fine but the `TForm1.WMDropFiles` method never gets called.

Anyone know the solution? Could be the Lazarus/Free-Pascal windows library behavior differs from Delphi's ?

FYI, I'm using lazarus-1.6.0-fpc-3.0.0-win32 on Windows 7 64 bit.

Comment: It is probably [number 2](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13482733/17034).

Comment: Nope, I have checked the lazarus app process has medium priority same as the explorer process. I also made c++ app that has same functionality and it works fine.

Comment: It's a big mistake to rely on the form's window not being recreated. Create a window handle whose life you control. AllocateHWnd in Delphi.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: correct me if I'm wrong, it seems AllocateHWnd doesn't exist in Lazarus.

Comment: Well then you should use something equivalent. I'm presuming that the GUI framework does recreate windows. You are making things up with `EnableWMDropFiles`. Try to go back to basics and understand things better rather than just pasting stuff at random.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: no need to be so rude here, I'm new in Lazarus that's why I asked help here. About `EnableWMDropFiles`, I just googled and read from here: http://forum.lazarus.freepascal.org/index.php?topic=3833.0. If that's certainly nothing to do with problem, then I will remove that from the code to avoid confusion. Thanks.

Comment: Instead of using OS-specific API just 1) Set `AllowDropFiles` property to `True`, 2) Implement `OnDropFiles` event. And it will work on the any supported OS. It is the Lazarus way ;o) Good luck. PS More reading [here](http://wiki.freepascal.org/Drag_and_Drop_sample)

Comment: I don't think that was rude. You need to stop guessing. That's my opinion. If you would rather I told you that you were great how would that help you?

Comment: @Abelisto: I know that way but my true goal is not dropping into form but to the TEdit (see my question post). Using `AllowDropFiles` sure it works for TForm but not the child components. @David: it sounds rude for me. No, I'm not guessing, did you read that I had said I googled and found that link? Really, I don't like debating in comment section, I'm expecting someone can contribute an answer rather than just making ad hominem comment.

Comment: I don't think you understand what ad hominem means. Good luck.

Comment: @david: No, I know what it means. Thanks.

Comment: Checking the mouse position is not a solution? In the `TForm1.FormDropFiles(...` `... if PtInRect(Edit1.ClientRect, Edit1.ScreenToClient(Mouse.CursorPos)) then ...`

Comment: I had read that trick too, but personally I'm a bit don't like it because by enable `AllowDropFiles` on TForm you give false impression that the form can accept drops. Btw I found this: http://forum.lazarus.freepascal.org/index.php?topic=779.0. It seems WM_DropFiles is disabled in lazarus because of cross-platform issue.

Comment: Message handling is different than delphi in lazarus. See http://wiki.lazarus.freepascal.org/Win32/64_Interface#Processing_non-user_messages_in_your_window

Comment: ... however a WM_SIZE handler works fine. Go figure...

Answer (score 1):

DragAcceptFiles is not true (for Lazarus), since it is a platform-dependent code ))

There is the correct cross-platform code: [OnDropFiles - Only works with dock icon, not with Application Form](http://forum.lazarus.freepascal.org/index.php/topic,11729.msg97561.html#msg97561)

He doesn't use "Windows", "Messages" and "ShellAPI".

1 Set property "AllowDropFiles" of MainForm to True;

2 Declaration of the procedure:

```
  type
  { TMainForm }
  TMainForm = class(TForm)
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
  private
    procedure OnApplicationDropFiles(Sender: TObject; const FileNames: array of String);
  public  
  end;
```

3 The procedure:

```
procedure TMainForm.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Application.AddOnDropFilesHandler(@OnApplicationDropFiles);
end;  

procedure TMainForm.OnApplicationDropFiles(Sender: TObject; const FileNames: array of String);
begin
  ShowMessage('Files dropped');
end;

procedure TMainForm.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Application.RemoveOnDropFilesHandler(@OnApplicationDropFiles);
end;
```

Comment: Alternatively to adding and removing an OnApplicationDropFiles handler you can also use a TApplicationProperties component which offers the OnDropFiles event directly. - Or you can use the OnDropFiles event of the form, just like eugene did onJuly 25.

Comment: How does this help being able to drop files only on the "edit" widget?

Answer (score 1):

Below answer solely elaborates on Win32WidgetSet which the question is apparently about.

First, as an answer to the question asked, the reason why `WM_DROPFILES` handler of the form is not called is that, simply the message is not *deliver*ed to the respective window procedure of the control class that the message is sent. LCL code is selective in what messages are *deliver*ed. Some details are in next paragraph, safe to skip...

---

After the message is dispatched (`DispatchMessage` of the Win32 API in procedure `TWin32WidgetSet.AppProcessMessages` of "win32object.inc" in "Win32Int.pp", which is the main message loop), the window procedure of the control's window (function `WindowProc` of "win32callback.inc" in "Win32Int.pp") constructs a `WindowProcHelper` object and calls its `DoWindowProc` (still in "win32callback.inc") function. This function has a huge message case, and it is here decided if a message will make it through the `DeliverMessage` function (which is in "LCLMessageGlue.pp"). `WM_DROPFILES` is handled differently and then it is not "deliver"ed. Any message which makes it to `DeliverMessage` is delivered to the control class' window procedure which the control it is sent belongs to (`TControl.WndProc` in "control.inc" of "controls.pp", or any override, f.i. `TWinControl.WndProc` in "wincontrol.inc" of "controls.pp") if it is a control, or dispatched otherwise.

---

Second, to achieve the desired behavior of handling dropped files on the edit control, one obvious solution, mentioned in so many places - even in lazarus' documentation as linked in a comment to the question, is to subclass the window of the control. Your subclass will be delivered the message before LCL has a chance to handle it, hence you can act on the message.

But, once you trace the code in `TWindowProcHelper.HandleDropFiles` in "win32callback.inc", it becomes apparent how easy it would be to set up the special handling of `WM_DROPFILES` in LCL so that only the edit control handles dropped files. Normally this is for handling at the form level as already mentioned in a [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38572470/243614), but a form also actually acts on  messages received on behalf of its children.

No need to go into specifics as it is just implementation detail and I don't know if it is intended but, set `AllowDropFiles` of the form to true, and then in the `OnCreate` handler of the form, unregister the form as a drop target (which is automatically registered) and register the edit.

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  AllowDropFiles:= True;
  DragAcceptFiles(Handle, False);
  DragAcceptFiles(Edit1.Handle, True);
end;
```

Only the edit will accept files, but you'd handle it still on the form's event handler.

```
procedure TForm1.FormDropFiles(Sender: TObject; const FileNames: array of String);
begin
  if Length(FileNames) > 0 then
    Edit1.Text := FileNames[0];
end;
```

It is also possible to use `Application.OnDropFiles` after the same setup, but I don't see any advantage over the previous method.

Answer (score 0):

```
procedure TForm1.FormDropFiles(Sender: TObject; const FileNames: array of String);
var i   : Integer;
    aTxt: String;
begin
    showmessage('oh it works, this is filename #1 ' + filenames[0])
end;
```

Comment: Sorry, this is not what I want, see again my question post, the first two paragraphs explain what I want to achieve.